# Gender specific pronouns for animals

Tags: gender, personal-pronoun

I have a female dog, and in English I would refer to her as *she*. Is it common in German to say Hündin instead of Hund, and could I use *Hund* and *sie* in the same sentence to refer to her or must I use *er*?

For example,

> Ich habe einen Hund. Sie heißt Pancake.

Where is the line between grammatical gender and biological gender?

Comment: I would say that there is no real line as the biological gender is not important to most people. Most non-dog-owners always say "he", even though they know my dogs are females. Dog-owners on the other hand care more about the biological gender and refer to a female dog as "she", but again, not all of them. It's one of those "delicate" topics where there is no real right or wrong, because even a female dog is a dog, and it's "der Hund" (masculine). The same (but the other way round) goes for cats. It's always "die liebe Katze", although it's a (male) "Kater" -.-

Comment: _"I have a female dog, and in English I would refer to her as she"_ and that would be a mistake: you should still refer to it as "it".

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze this situation: Tom has a dog, Lisa has a cat, Lara has a guinea pig and Georg has a bird. But you don't know the names of any of those animals:

> If you know that the animals are male:
>   Tom hat **einen Hund**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt. *OR:* Tom hat **einen Rüden**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt.
>   Lisa hat **einen Kater**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt.
>   Lara hat **ein Meerschweinchen**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **es** heißt.
>   Georg hat **einen Vogel**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt.
>
> If you know that the animals are female:
>   Tom hat **eine Hündin**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **sie** heißt.
>   Lisa hat **eine Katze**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **sie** heißt.
>   Lara hat **ein Meerschweinchen**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **es** heißt.
>   Georg hat **einen Vogel**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt.

Also interesting is the case when you don't know the animals's genders:

> If you **don't** know the animals's genders:
>   Tom hat **einen Hund**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt.
>   Lisa hat **eine Katze**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **sie** heißt.
>   Lara hat **ein Meerschweinchen**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **es** heißt.
>   Georg hat **einen Vogel**. Ich weiß nicht, wie **er** heißt.

As usual in German language, the pronoun's grammatical gender is **always** the same as the grammatical gender of the noun that is referred by the pronoun. And this are the genders of the used animal-words:

- **Der Hund**
  Grammatical gender: **male** → pronoun: **er**
  Used for: male dogs and dogs who's biological gender is unknown
- **Der Rüde**
  Grammatical gender: **male** → pronoun: **er**
  Used for: male dogs
- **Die Hündin**
  Grammatical gender: **female** → pronoun: **sie**
  Used for: female dogs
- **Die Katze**
  Grammatical gender: **female** → pronoun: **sie**
  Used for: female cats and cats who's biological gender is unknown
- **Der Kater**
  Grammatical gender: **male** → pronoun: **er**
  Used for: male cats
- **Das Meerschweinchen**
  Grammatical gender: **neuter** → pronoun: **es**
  Used for: all guinea pigs (male, female and unknown biological gender)
- **Der Vogel**
  Grammatical gender: **male** → pronoun: **er**
  Used for: all birds (male, female and unknown biological gender)

But there are many other names of animals that are not used as pets:

**pigs:**

- **Das Schwein**
  Grammatical gender: **neuter** → pronoun: **es**
  Used for: pigs who's biological gender is unknown.
- **Der Eber**
  Grammatical gender: **male** → pronoun: **er**
  Used for: male pigs.
- **Die Sau**
  Grammatical gender: **female** → pronoun: **sie**
  Used for: female pigs.

**goats:**

- **Die Ziege**
  Grammatical gender: **female** → pronoun: **sie**
  Used for: goats who's biological gender is unknown.
- **Der Bock; der Ziegenbock**
  Grammatical gender: **male** → pronoun: **er**
  Used for: male goats.
- **Die Geiß**
  Grammatical gender: **female** → pronoun: **sie**
  Used for: female goats.

You can find more names of animals here: [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Bezeichnungen_für_Haus-_und_Wildtiere](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Bezeichnungen_f%C3%BCr_Haus-_und_Wildtiere)

Comment: You make it sound as if the example in the question (_Hund … sie_ or _Katze … er_) was strictly not acceptable, but it really is. The use of gender-specific animal nouns is quite optional.

Comment: @Crissov: »Ich habe **einen Hund** (m). **Sie** (f) heißt Pancake« is grammatically wrong, because the genders doesn't match. This is what I wanted to express in my answer. German grammar allows this variations: »Ich habe **einen Hund** (m). **Er** (m) heißt Pancake.« - »Ich habe **eine Hündin** (f). **Sie** (f) heißt Pancake.« - »Ich habe **einen Hund** (m). **Er** (m) ist ein Weibchen, **er** (m) heißt Pancake.« - »Ich habe einen Hund. **Es** (n) ist **ein Weibchen** (n), **es** (n) heißt Pancake.«

Comment: Sure, but pronouns don’t necessarily have to agree in grammatical gender with antecedents, they can be based on sex, standard example: _das Mädchen … sie_.

Comment: @Crissov: »Das Mädchen« ist ein sehr gute Beispiel: Falsch: »Dort drüben stehen **ein Mädchen** (n). **Sie** (f) hat blondes Haar.« Richtig: »Dort drüben stehen **ein Mädchen** (n). **Es** (n) hat blondes Haar.«

Comment: Nein, das ist ganz sicher nicht falsch. Es ist noch nicht mal ungewöhnlich und wird mit zunehmender Entfernung von Nomen und Pronomen immer wahrscheinlicher. Pronomen funktionieren sowohl innersprachlich als auch außersprachlich und wer behauptet, dass nur das eine oder das andere richtig sei, hat entweder keine Ahnung von (der deutschen) Sprache oder möchte seine Vorstellung von gutem Stil untermauern. –1

Comment: Man könnte auch noch **der Hahn** oder **die Henne** anstatt **der Vogel** sagen.

Comment: @SteffenRoller: Hahn und Henne werden nur für Hühnervögel verwendet (Hühner, Fasane, Wachteln u.ä.). Eine männliche Ente ist kein Hahn, sondern ein Erpel oder Enterich. Eine männliche Gans ist ein Ganter. Und dass ein männlicher Kanarienvogel ebenfalls kein Hahn ist, weiß jemand mit deinem Nachnamen vermutlich ohnehin schon seit früher Kindheit: https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=ssl#q=männlicher+Kanarienvogel

Comment: Das Ferkel würde noch in die Schweinesammlung passen, was zwar biologisch kein Geschlecht ist, aber sprachlich.

Answer (score 1):

*Hund* is a generic masculine noun, *Katze* a generic feminine noun and *Eichhörnchen* a generic neuter noun. The rule is that you fall back to generic nouns *when biological gender is not important*. Example:

> Hunde sind an die Leine zu nehmen. Ich hatte mal einen Hund, der hat sich dauernd gewälzt. Ich hatte in meinem Leben viele Hunde. Ich mag Hunde. Ich hasse es, wenn Hunde an mir hochspringen. Ich liebe Katzen. Ich hatte mal eine Katze, die hat mir fast jede Woche eine Maus angeschleppt.

Gender is completely unimportant here. Your example however violates the rule as you refer to gender in the second sentence. This implies that her gender actually *is* important to you, therefore you have to use it in the first sentence (at least it would sound more natural):

> Ich habe eine Hündin. Sie heißt Pancake. Ich hatte in meinem Leben viele Hunde, Rüden wie Hündinnen; wenn die Hündinnen läufig waren, war das sehr lästig. Der Rüde/Hund meines Nachbarn wollte meine Hündin bespringen. Ich musste meiner Hündin die Eierstöcke entfernen lassen (I deem *Hund* somewhat tolerable here).

The situation is easier with Eichhörnchen, as the word is neuter:

> Ich hatte zwei Eichhörnchen, Rudolf und Bianca. In meinem Garten hat ein Eichhörnchen geworfen.

You would refer to gender with *Männchen* und *Weibchen*:

> Das Weibchen holte dann leider der Fuchs, das Männchen hat sich aber dann um die Jungen gekümmert.

So you cannot – or at least should not – use *er* in your example. Again, you could, if gender is not important:

> Ich hatte einen Hund. Wenn man den alleine gelassen hat, hat er die ganze Nachbarschaft zusammengebellt.

Even if it was a female dog, you don’t care about her being female in this story.

However it is more tolerable to not use the correct gender, even though it appears in the sentence, as opposed to humans:

> Meine Afra war ein toller Hund!
>   ?Merkel war ein (your opinion here) Bundeskanzler.

Some feminists use female forms in their texts and claim to include men. This is wrong, as the male/female opposite of a generic noun always exclude the other gender.

Comment: I would *prefer* to use *sex* when talking about animals, because there is no such think as *gender* (think gender mainstreaming and all the other craploads of stuff connected to genders) for animals.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich habe einen Hund. *Sie* hat Angst vor Rollläden und anderen Hunden. *Sie* heißt Célia.

This is more or less how I would introduce my dog out there. However, I might also say (rarer):

> Ich habe einen Hund. *Er* hat Angst vor Rollläden und anderen Hunden. *Er* heißt Célia.

It really depends on how much you want your dog to be recognised as female. Version one might cause weird looks for a second or two, but they’ll be satisfied when they hear a female name.

You *can not*, however, use something like *meine Hund*. If it’s that important, use *meine Hündin*.

Comment: Lesen, schreiben, hören und sprechen sind sequentielle Prozesse. Das sprachliche Geschlecht wird nicht durch spätere Sätze festgelegt. "Albert Einstein nahm ihr Fahrrad und fuhr zur Uni. Sie ist eine patente Person."

Comment: @userunknown Leider verstehe ich diesen deinen Kommentar nicht …?

Comment: Was verstehst Du daran nicht? Sequenzieller Prozess? Dass sich ein "sie" nicht auf eine Celia beziehen kann, die erst im nächsten Satz genannt wird, während vorher von einem Hund die Rede war, also keinem femininen Subjekt, sondern einem maskulinen? "Ich kenne eine patente Person. Sie fährt per Rad zur Uni. Ihr Name ist Albert Einstein."  Verständlichher?

Comment: @userunknown Ah, jetzt weiß ich, was du meinst.

Answer (score 0):

Im Beispiel "Ich habe einen Hund. Sie heißt Pancake." ist das Wort "sie" ein Ersatz für ein anderes Wort. Dieses andere Wort can "Der Hund" sein, aber auch "die Hündin". Ich kann ersetzen:

```
"Ich habe einen Hund. Der Hund heißt Pancake." -> "Er heißt Pancake."
"Ich habe einen Hund. Die Hündin heißt Pancake." -> "Sie heißt Pancake."
```

Beides ist richtig.

Comment: Der zweite Satz provoziert den Verdacht, Du hättest einen männlichen Hund und eine Hündin. "Sie" ist auch kein Ersatz, sondern ein Bezug, und muss sich auf eine sprachlich weibliche Einheit beziehen.  "Ich habe einen Hund. Sie heißt Pancake." ist also schlicht falsch..

Comment: @userunknown Gehe ich recht in der Annahme, dass der Downvote auf meiner Antwort von dir stammt, und die Begründung in deinem Kommentar liegt? ;)

Comment: @Jan: Hast Du eine Sockenpuppe namens gnasher729?

Comment: @userunknown Nein, ich habe keine Sockenpuppen, aber nachdem ich wegen des Downvotes meine Antwort besucht habe, habe ich hier den Kommentar gefunden, der möglicherweise auch auf meine Antwort (die ja essentiell das gleiche sagt, nur anders) auch zutrifft. Da habe ich mal auf Verdacht kommentiert. (Außerdem hätte ich nie eine Sockenpuppe Monospace-Formatierung verwenden lassen, es sei denn, es ginge um Code.)

Answer (score 0):

It all is just as bad in English - possibly worse.

English speakers do not even have a single word for the animal species which includes bulls, calves, steers, heifers, and cows.

At least they can all be called "it".